# Polymer + Firebase (Polymerfire): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined': 'this.$.query.ref.push(...)'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer

I'm following a [Polymer + Firebase tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AHDSGitDP0) using the Polymer App Tool Kit (initiated with the polymer CLI).

When I try to push data to a Firebase collection, I get the following error:

`Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'`

Here's my code (firebase app is initiated in my-app.html with name "firebase-app"):

```
<dom-module id="add-model">
    <!-- Defines the element's style and local DOM -->
    <template>
        <firebase-auth user="{{user}}" app-name="firebase-app"></firebase-auth>
        <firebase-query
                app-name="firebase-app"
                id="query"
                path="/users/[[user.uid]]/models"
                data="{{model}}">
        </firebase-query>
        <paper-input id="modelName" label="Model Name" "></paper-input>
        <paper-button class="create" id="create" on-tap="create" raised>Create</paper-button>
    </template>
    <!-- Creates the element's prototype and registers it -->
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'add-model',
            properties: {
                data: {
                    type: Object
                }
            },
            create: function() {
               this.$.query.ref.push({
                   name: this.$.modelName.value
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend comparing your code to the [Polycast #58 source in GitHub](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/tree/0def6a8/ep58-firebase-db-demo), which might reveal the problem more clearly to you.

`this.$.query.ref` (`<firebase-query>.ref`) refers to the [`ref`](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/aa93f5f/firebase-database-behavior.html#L25) property of `Polymer.FirebaseDatabaseBehavior`, which is [computed](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/aa93f5f/firebase-database-behavior.html#L73-L79) with:

```
__computeRef: function(db, path) {
  if (db == null ||
      path == null ||
      !this.__pathReady(path) ||
      this.disabled) {
    return null;
  }

  return db.ref(path);
},
```

Note that `db.ref(path)` [never returns `null`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#ref), so `ref` being `null` must be a result of the `if` statement. Evaluating each condition might uncover the issue:

- `db == null`

  - This property is [computed](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/aa93f5f/firebase-database-behavior.html#L69-L71) from `app.database()` ([never returns `null`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database)), or is set to `null` when [`app`](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/aa93f5f7888a11f58c5dfe9efe9e2434938b9a35/firebase-common-behavior.html#L19) is not defined (by `<firebase-app>`). Have you declared `<firebase-app>` with the proper `app-name` before importing the element that uses `<firebase-query>`?
- `path == null`

  - You might not have set [`<firebase-query>.path`](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/aa93f5f/firebase-database-behavior.html#L34). This is clearly not the case.
- [`!this.__pathReady(path)`](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/aa93f5f/firebase-database-behavior.html#L100-L102)

  - One of the path components might be an empty string or uninitialized. For your path (`/users/[[user.uid]]/models`), it's possible that `user` is not yet defined (user is not yet logged in), which results in an empty string in that path component (`/users//models`).
- `this.disabled`

  - You might have set [`<firebase-query>.disabled`](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/aa93f5f/firebase-database-behavior.html#L45). This is clearly not the case.

Comment: Amazing, logical, and well-explained answer! Turns out the problem lies with the first point: firebase-app is not properly imported:
I have my firebase-app configuration in a another module `<firebase-config>` so I can easily reuse the firebase data in my app. `<firebase-config>` is in my main app container view (`my-app.html`).
If I move `<firebase-config>` from `my-app.html` to `add-model.html` it works, but I have functionality in `my-app.html` which also requires `<firebase-config>`.
Loading the module twice returns `Uncaught Error: Firebase App named 'firebase-app' already exists.`

Comment: Posted a new question regarding my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443228/polymer-firebase-polymerfire-firebase-query-not-working-inside-single-pag
Thanks again for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: @Dean No problem :)

Comment: Can you have a look at my other question (link in 2nd comment)? It's what I'm running into regarding declaring `<firebass-app>` in my application. I've been at it all morning but haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to answer later today if nobody gets to it.