# Polymer + Firebase (Polymerfire): <firebase-query> not working inside single page app view (with <firebase-app> located in my-app.html)

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymer-starter-kit, polymerfire

I'm trying to push data to Firebase using Polymerfire and the Polymer App Toolbox template:

- `my-app.html` contains a configured `<firebase-app>` component.
- `my-models.html` (which is a page configured in `my-app.html` routes) contains a `<add-model>` component
- `<add-model>` is a form with a `<firebase-query>`, `<firebase-auth>`, input, and submit button.
- I attempt to push data using `<firebase-query>` with the following function in the `add-model.html` `Polymer` object:

  ```
  Polymer({
      is: 'add-model',
      properties: {
          data: {
              type: Object
          }
      },
      create: function() {
         this.$.query.ref.push({
             name: this.$.myModelName.value
          });
      }
  });
  ```

  #### Outcome
- Calling `push` on the `<firebase-query>` object in `add-model.html` returns `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` ([explained in this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435694/polymer-firebase-polymerfire-cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-th/41436543#41436543), in our case it's because `<firebase-app>` does not appear to be properly declared).
- Moving `<firebase-app>` from `my-app.html` to `add-model.html` file does make the `push` function work, but then `my-app.html` loses its Firebase functionality.
- Calling `<firebase-app>` in both my-app.html and add-model.html returns `Uncaught Error: Firebase App named 'firebase-app' already exists.`
- `<firebase-auth>` does work in `add-model.html` and returns a `[[user]]` object.

How do I make `firebase-query` properly communicate with `firebase-app` from my route?

Comment: firebase-query is immutable.  you cannot use it to change firebase data.  you should use firebase-document for that.

https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/issues/104

Comment: @RyanTyler Pushing data works when `firebase-app` is called directly in the component though?

Comment: @RyanTyler I just followed the instructions from that link and got it working by dynamically creating a firebase-document and then doing `doc.save(...)` in the 'create' function!

Comment: @RyanTyler  Correction, it's not working. I just followed the instructions from that link which results in `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @RyanTyler While it does make sense that a query would be immutable, it appears to be still possible to modify `ref`s from `firebase-query`, as demonstrated in a recent [Polycast](https://youtu.be/9AHDSGitDP0?t=8m26s) ([source](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/blob/0def6a8c6b5764547d43bffefc2b464498b5857d/ep58-firebase-db-demo/public/my-notes.html#L86-L95)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR:** The solution is to import `polymerfire/polymerfire.html` (even if not all elements used in that file) in the same file as your `<firebase-app>` declaration.

---

Your `my-app.html` probably imports `polymerfire/firebase-app.html` (and no other imports from Polymerfire); and `my-models.html` probably imports only `polymerfire/firebase-query.html` and `polymerfire/firebase-auth.html`, assuming those are the only Polymerfire elements used in that file.

I've identified the cause (but not necessarily the root cause). The symptoms are exhibited when `polymerfire.html` is not imported in the same file as the declaration of `<firebase-app>`.

`polymerfire.html` imports all elements from Polymerfire, including [`Polymer.FirebaseCommonBehavior`](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/2a88d01/firebase-common-behavior.html), which defines the `app` property seen in all Polymerfire elements. I'm guessing the Firebase SDK requires all Polymerfire elements imported before `app` initialization in order to populate the `app` object appropriately. Otherwise, when `firebase-query` initializes, [`app.database` will be undefined](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/aa93f5f/firebase-database-behavior.html#L70), which prevents its [`ref` property from initializing](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/aa93f5f/firebase-database-behavior.html#L74), leading to runtime errors when you try to use the methods of the Polymerfire elements. In the case of `this.$.query.ref.push(...)`, the error seen would be:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: You're a savior, @tony19! Thanks so much! This should definitely go in the `polymerfire` (I also saw multiple users commenting on the Polycast that they were having this issue).

Comment: @Dean No problem :) I'll comment on the Polycast.

Comment: Similar problems of trying different element for '<firebase-app>' and '<firebase-query>'. I've tried this solution and it doesn't work. I'm using [this template](https://github.com/StartPolymer/progressive-web-app-template) by the way. I also uninstall and re-install polymerfire and it seems this template is using different version of polymerfire. Can you have a look at this issue as well, @tony19 ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the above answer to import polymerfire/polymerfire.html right on the money. Additionally I would add that my particular app was very very fussy about exactly where every import and firebase element was located. Most of the polycasts (such as #58 referenced above) seem quite straightforward and easy to get right. This particular one took a lot of experimentation with where the elements and imports were located, due to scoping or visibility or other issues that I never figured out.

Hope this helps someone else in the same situation I was in.

I'd also bet that a visitor in 2018 or later would find this post obsolete, because it would seem likely to be improved by then.

Answer (score 1):

For me the key was to declare `firebase-app` before declaring the rest of the WebComponents that had `firebase-query` or `firebase-document` inside. During debugging I realized that the firebase properties of the child WebComponents were set before they were declared in the `firebase-app` element itself.

This is the order that worked for me:

```
<firebase-app
    name='someName'
    auth-domain="xxx.firebaseapp.com"
    database-url="xxx.firebaseio.com/"
    api-key="my-api-key">
</firebase-app>
```

And all the elements that use `query` or `document` should come only after this:

```
<some-component>
...
   <firebase-document
       app-name='someName'
       id="query"
       path="/app/firstName"
       data="{{testFirstName}}">
   </firebase-document> 
...
</some-component>
```