# No data returned using polymefire firebase-query element

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymerfire

I'm creating a dom-module to display my firebase data in a div. I followed along with the Polycast video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AHDSGitDP0&t=639s but the firebase-query component is not pulling in the data. No data appears in the console other than my signed in user data and there are no errors. I saw that other people had issues pulling in data with polymerfire and I tried the solution here but no luck: [Polymer + Firebase (Polymerfire): <firebase-query> not working inside single page app view (with <firebase-app> located in my-app.html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443228/polymer-firebase-polymerfire-firebase-query-not-working-inside-single-pag/41450672#41450672)

Could someone help with this?

In my main html page I have the following:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-database-script.html"> 
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
    <link rel="import" href="elements/browse-events.html"> <!-- my custom component -->
</head>

<body>
            <firebase-app
                api-key=""
                auth-domain=""
                database-url=""
                project-id=""
                storage-bucket=""
                messaging-sender-id="">
            </firebase-app>

            <!-- my custom component -->
            <browse-events></browse-events>

</body>
```

Here's the code in my component's file (browse-events.html)

```
<!-- dependencies -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-database-script.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-database-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-query.html">

<dom-module id="browse-events"> 
    <template>
        <firebase-query
                        id="query-all"
                        app-name="authtest-54513"
                        path="/events"
                        data="{{events}}">
        </firebase-query>

        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[events]]" as="event">
            <div> 
                <h1>[[event.title]]</h1>
            </div>
        </template>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is:'browse-events',
            properties: {
                events: {
                    type: Object
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use app-name in firebase-query you need to specify the `name` in `firebase-app`. If you only use one `firebase-app` in your app you can leave out the `name` in `firebase-app` and the `app-name` in your other polymerfire elements.

Property `events` is likely an Array instead of an Object:

> If the child nodes of the query are objects (most cases), `data` will
>   be an array of those objects with an extra `$key` field added to
>   represent the key. If the child nodes are non-object leaf values,
>   `data` will be an array of objects of the structure `{$key: key, $val:
>   val}`.
>   https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/master/firebase-query.html

On a side note: You only need to import `firebase-query` inside your `browse-events` element. Firebase-query will import the scripts it needs to run itself. (same for firebase-app in you main html page)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it, specifically when I took away the app-name from firebase-query. Many thanks!